# Multiple logger instance for each application modules

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.reactive

I started to create a log system based on Observable Pattern. For that I use Reactive Extensions.
I have an IObservable called ILogInfo and a IObserver called ILogObserver.
I have a main application with various modules that used shared libraries. Each module implements an observer of ILogInfo and the modules can work in parallel. My problem here, is that I would like to observe only the ILogInfo registered in the scope of my module.

[image: Scheme Application]

In this scheme I have two modules (Module A and Module B), each module uses many libraries which push information via ILogInfo. When LibC push a new ILogInfo I would like that only the calling module catch (observe) the information. For example when the call comes from Module B, I don't the information to be observed by Module A. How could I do this ?

Comment: How about having a 'Sender' field in ILogInfo? Then you could push the logs on a common bus and the consumers could filter the stream using logBus.Where(l=>l.Sender == moduleA)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but if I do this I must forward the Sender information in each level and I have too many libraries to consider this solution for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a question about Rx really. You need to be able to get calling context from the ILogInfo to route it appropriately.

You can provide either provide that context explicitly from the caller (the sender suggestion in the comments seems like a simple, workable suggestion of this) or do an expensive stackwalk to determine the calling module (which won't work in asynchronous situations) or otherwise you'll have to maintain the caller in ExecutionContext by setting data in the [LogicalCallContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.logicalcallcontext.aspx) - this works in more asynchronous situations but is more complex.

I don't know about your specific situation, but given the need to isolate logging so throughly, I wonder if hosting multiple copies of the libraries in separate per-Module AppDomains might be easier, giving you complete isolation.

I hope there's a really good reason for this requirement, because it feels very complicated when existing logging frameworks have good solutions for providing context (like activity tracing in the logging application block and in WCF for example).

Comment: Thank you James for your answer. We decide to isolate each module in an AppDomain. This is more simple, more secure and it works very well :). It remains only to find us how to exchange data between AppDomain because we have a library that centralizes information between different modules.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with James here. This isn't really an Rx question.

I also have a question of how will you deal with logging where many modules reference the same library?

Is there a reason you are not considering a common Logging solution like Log4Net?

Comment: You're right, with James, this isn't an Rx question, I've change my question title.

Comment: We don't use Log4Net, NLog or other logging solution because we don't want to be dependent on a specific log library. The main advantage we found to use Rx is that we could implement many Observer for a module which could log information with NLog or write them to a console or display them in the user interface.

Comment: I understand this thinking. I would have thought however that a simple ILogger interface that wraps the implementation would suffice. Then you just use categories and listeners to observe the logs.